# MD5 sum of a image column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I have a checksum (be it `MD5` or anything else) of a image column calculated in SQL Server? i.e. something like

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', d.data)
FROM ATTACHMENTDATA D
```

> 8116 Argument data type image is invalid for argument 2 of hashbytes
>   function

Trying:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), d.data))
FROM ATTACHMENTDATA D
```

results in:

> 529 Explicit conversion from data type image to nvarchar is not
>   allowed

If that matters I use Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.4000 (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: `image` is deprecated since 2005 (I think), you should use `varbinary(max)`. Besides, it makes no sense to cast binary data to text as you tried to do

Comment: How will you use this checksum? SQL Server has functions for securely signing data, while change-detection checksums are best calculated before storing the value in the database

Comment: Be aware that `hashbytes` can accept no more than 8000 bytes in the input argument. Depending on the data and its use `hashbytes` may be suitable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast data column to `VARBINARY`:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('md5', CAST(d.data AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
FROM ATTACHMENTDATA D
```

`MD5` is weak hash algorithm use `SHA1`, `SHA2_256` or `SHA2_512` instead.

Note also that: `IMAGE` datatype is deprecated.

Comment: Whether MD5 is appropriate depends on its usage. It's good enough to detect changes, not good for encryption or signing. On the other hand, SHA2 algorithms may be *faster* because they have optimized OS/hardware support and use a larger block size - ie there are fewer blocks to calculate

Answer (score 0):

try converting it to a VARBINARY(MAX)

Also, see this note from Microsoft at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms187993.aspx

[image]